# Can a 10/100 Ethernet port handle 120 Mbps?

Tags: ethernet

If i buy a MI router 3 which has a 10/100 wan port, will it handle a 120 Mbps internet speed or it's gonna be limited to 100 Mbps?

Comment: Will be limited. You need router that has gigabit ports

Comment: 10/100 is usually a rating for a LAN card or LAN ports. I have never heard of WAN ports being referred to that way. Are you talking Xiaomi Mi Wi-Fi router 3? That is what came up the most when I searched "MI router 3". That one says featuring data transfer rates of even 1167 Mbps. and WIFI between 300 -867Mbps. That is theoretical though.

Comment: Thanks for all of you for the answers! imo: the wifi transfer rate means a logical maximum, what people can probably use out by transfering files from a wifi device to another, but according to  Alex it will be limited, so when downloading from the web the wan port will bottleneck the rate over wifi as well I think. 
But i decided to buy this router anyway and connect my main PC directly into the modem instead of connecting into this router, and I'll use the xiaomi router as an access point.
When I get it, I'll test the speed and Post the results here. Thaks for the help!

Comment: @ÁkosZorin Still waiting for your speed test. :D

Comment: I have Netgear WNDR3400v3 with 10/100 wan port and a 200 mbps internet connection. Just wanted to check what is the max speed I can get on 10/100 wan port.

Answer (score 1):

No, it most likely won't *in theory*. In *practice* you're unlikely to be bottlenecked by it in most cases since most sites would be slower than that anyway.

In practice, with most ISPs, your *downstream* and *upstream* are different as well. So, under ideal, perfect conditions, you'd be losing out on a bit of speed on downstream. I'd actually be more concerned with other things, like whether the hardware can manage the traffic, and general reliability.

In my *opinion* that's a rather strangely designed piece of kit but unless you manage to bring it to its knees, it's probably good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The wanport will ensure that the internet speed will not excel 100mbit, but if a device has only a 10/100 mbit port, it is likely that its internal processing power is going to be far less. I would recommend searching for a different router.